# Why does Preview not follow the Preferences?

Tags: preview, preferences

In Preview, I chose the settings

1. Start on the last viewed page
2. Open each file in its own window

However, it seems that the settings are not respected.

1. When opening a PDF file, the first page is shown.
2. When opening a PDF file, it is added as a tab to a PDF file that is already open.

What is happening here?

(Preview version 10.0)

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Might just work...

Comment: @Thinkr Yes, several times. Preview keeps not respecting the indicated settings ever since.